# Invisible when page load "No result found"

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
$search_code = $_POST['search_code'];
global $wpdb;
$helloworld_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT s_image FROM search_code WHERE s_code = $search_code");
 if (empty($helloworld_id)) { 
 echo '<div class="no_results">No results found</div>'; 
 }else 
 { ?>
  <img src="http://igtlaboratories.com/wp-content/uploads/images/<?php echo $helloworld_id; ?>"style="width:200px;height: auto;">
<?php
  }
}
```

I using this code but when page load by default "no result found" visible . how i disable on page load. Any help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should implement some if statement to check. And the run the query if your all requirements get satisfies

Answer (score 1):

It simple, add Condition above the your search code and put your all code inside this condition. Please check below code

Used [isset ()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) in condition for Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL and [!empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)

```
if(isset($_POST['search_code']) && !empty($_POST['search_code']))
{
    // Your code goes here 
    $search_code = $_POST['search_code'];
    global $wpdb;
    $helloworld_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT s_image FROM search_code WHERE s_code = $search_code");
    if (empty($helloworld_id)) { 
        echo '<div class="no_results">No results found</div>'; 
    }else { ?>
        <img src="http://igtlaboratories.com/wp-content/uploads/images/<?php echo $helloworld_id; ?>"style="width:200px;height: auto;">
    <?php }
}
```

Comment: Empty search code could be a valid condition for that block of code, it may be fine to run an empty search.

Answer (score 0):

just try this

```
if(isset($_POST['search_code']) && !empty($_POST['search_code']))
{
    $search_code = $_POST['search_code'];
    global $wpdb;
    $helloworld_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT s_image FROM search_code WHERE s_code = $search_code");
    if (empty($helloworld_id)) { 
        echo '<div class="no_results">No results found</div>'; 
    }else{ ?>
        <img src="http://igtlaboratories.com/wp-content/uploads/images/<?php echo $helloworld_id; ?>"style="width:200px;height: auto;">
    <?php }
}
```

Comment: Empty search code could be a valid condition for that block of code, it may be fine to run an empty search.

Comment: please approve answer so it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

This is undefined index

```
   $search_code = $_POST['search_code'];
```

So I would change that to

```
   $search_code = isset( $_POST['search_code'] ) ? $_POST['search_code']  : false;
```

Then wrap the other part in an if statement

```
 if( $search_code ){
    global $wpdb;

    $helloworld_id = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT s_image FROM search_code WHERE s_code = $search_code");

    if (empty($helloworld_id)) { 
         echo '<div class="no_results">No results found</div>'; 
    }else{
        echo '<img src="http://igtlaboratories.com/wp-content/uploads/images/'.$helloworld_id.'"style="width:200px;height: auto;">';
    }
  }//end if $search_code
```

Also mixing the `echo` with the PHP start and end blocks in the if else statement looked weird to me so I fixed that too.